# Upload image to webpage and scale/move/rotate on screen

Tags: jquery, image, upload

It's been a while since I needed to do something like this, and in the past I have used Flash to acheive this.

What are the best solutions out there now to do this? I'm thinking jQuery? I don't want to use HTML5 yet as the site I'm building is an ecommerce one and so has to cater for all browsers.

Anyone have any good recommendations?

Thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do it in JavaScript that supports all browsers yet. [Here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) is a good tutorial on how to upload files using JavaScript. It doesn't use jQuery, but it's fairly simple. [This tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) is good for dragging and dropping files. Using the two I managed to create a drag and drop upload script, but unfortunately not all browsers support this. Chrome and Firefox do, IE don't, and I'm not sure about the others. Short answer? There's **no** JS only way to upload files for all browsers